# How to only clear certain parts of a canvas with VB

Tags: vb.net

On a form I am using I have 4 picture boxes, each with images drawn on them, when i try to clear, and then redraw the image on **one** the others are also cleared, is there any way to only clear the contents of one picture box, or even one specific part of that picture box?
These are the two parts of code which create the images in the graphs:

```
Dim myPen As New Pen(Color.Lime, 1)
Dim Canvas1 As Graphics
Dim Canvas2 As Graphics
Dim Canvas3 As Graphics
Dim Canvas4 As Graphics
Canvas1 = picGraph1.CreateGraphics()
Canvas2 = picGraph2.CreateGraphics()
Canvas3 = picGraph3.CreateGraphics()
Canvas4 = picGraph4.CreateGraphics()

Canvas1.DrawRectangle(myPen, X * i, Y - Height, CSng(picGraph1.Width / NumberOfBars), Height)
Canvas2.DrawRectangle(myPen, X * i, Y - Height, CSng(picGraph1.Width / NumberOfBars), Height)
Canvas3.DrawRectangle(myPen, X * i, Y - Height, CSng(picGraph1.Width / NumberOfBars), Height)
Canvas4.DrawRectangle(myPen, X * i, Y - Height, CSng(picGraph1.Width / NumberOfBars), Height)
```

And this is the part of code which I would like to clear just one of the picture boxes:

```
Dim myPen As New Pen(Color.Lime, 1)
Dim Canvas1 As Graphics
Dim NumberOfBars As Integer = List.Length - 1
Canvas1 = picGraph1.CreateGraphics()
Canvas1.Clear(Color.Gray)   'clears the current contents of the graphs
```

However when it runs it clears all four picture boxes, is there any way to just clear the one?

Comment: No-repro. `Canvas1.Clear` clears just `Canvas1`.

Comment: Thats what i would have thought however when i run the code it clears all 4 boxes :/

Comment: You are using `.CreateGraphics()`. When you change anything that causes a redraw of the parent Form, everything is redrawn. Since nothing is there to redraw the `PictureBoxes` DC, all of them will be reset. Use the `Paint` event to draw on your controls. Search SO about `Graphics` and `Paint`. You'll find a ridiculous amount of these  *suggestions*. To `.Clear()` a specific part of a *canvas* use the overload of `Invalidate()` that allows to specify a `Region` or a `Rectangle`.

Comment: @Require_Assistance Can you reproduce it in a new project with nothing but four pictureboxes on the form?

Comment: @Jimi is right.  When you use `CreateGraphics`, anything you draw will not survive the next time the form is repainted by Windows.  To see this, comment out your call to `Clear` and then after the picture boxes have something in them, minimize your form and then restore it.  You should see that all your careful work is gone!  Also you are leaking graphics resources since you are not disposing of your `Graphics` instances.